# GAE bulkloader csv delimiter error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, yaml, bulkloader

I have a file in the following format

name- stuffinside -description
name- stuffinside -description
"ame- stuffinside -description

and I have the following bit as my bulkloader code:

t

```
ransformers: 
- kind: storeItem 
connector: csv 
connector_options: 
encoding: utf-8 
column_list: [name, stuffinside,description]
 property_map:
 - property: key
 external_name: name export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string

- property: name
  external_name: name

- property: stuffinside
  external_name: stuffinside
  import_transform: "lambda x: x.split('-')"

- property: description
  external_name: description
```

the problem I'm having is that I can't get it to read the file
split it by the "-" symbol and have 3 different parts. I want it to be like

```
name = x[0]
stuffinside =x[1]
description = x[2]
```

Which reading in from a file I have no problem doing that, but I have no clue how do it in this app engine bulkloading format. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure "-" is a good symbol to use as a field separator?  It seems quite likely the content might contain that symbol and screw up your fields.

Would you convert the "-" to tabs first and then follow this sample:

From http://bulkloadersample.appspot.com/showfile/bulkloader.yaml:

```
# A sample using a TSV file with no header, specifying the columns here.
- model: models.Visit
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
    encoding: windows-1252
    # TSV is specified using an extra parameter of the Python csv module.
    import_options:
      dialect: excel-tab
    export_options:
      dialect: excel-tab
    # Columns here are a sequence in YAML, so can be specified in either block
    # or flow style. This is short enough that I'll use flow style.
    column_list: [visitid, customer, date, score, activities]
  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: visitid
      export_transform: datastore.Key.name
    - property: customer
      external_name: customer
      import_transform: transform.create_foreign_key('Customer')
      export_transform: datastore.Key.name
    - property: visit_date
      external_name: date
      import_transform: transform.import_date_time('%m/%d/%Y')
      export_transform: transform.export_date_time('%m/%d/%Y')
    - property: score
      external_name: score
      import_transform: float
    - property: activities
      external_name: activities
      # This is a CSV list of strings inside the TSV file.
      import_transform: "lambda x: x.split(',')"
      export_transform: "','.join"
```

Comment: well part of my problem is that some of the text inbetween has commas. So I want to split it by another delimiter.
and I've manually gone through all of my content. there are no - in odd places. its only in the places i put them.
name-stuffinside-description

Comment: name-stuffinside-description


new lines and that format repeated throughout.